# Finding faster way to compute a matrix using MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

I am looking for a faster way to compute a matrix using MATLAB:

Given an m-by-n matrix `A`, I would like to return a matrix `B` with the additions of all `i`th and the `j`th rows such that `j >= i`. E.g.,
Let `A=[1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5; 3 4 5 6]`, then `B` can be computed as

```matlab
idx=1;
nbrows=size(A,1);
B=zeros(nbrows*(nbrows+1)/2,size(A,2)); % the size of B can be determined
for i = 1:nbrows
  for j = i:nbrows
    B(idx,:) = A(i,:) + A(j,:);
    idx = idx + 1;
  end
end
```

Now, I have a very large `A`, and I would like to know how to compute the matrix `B` in a more efficient way.

How can this computation be sped-up?

Comment: How big is your input that speed is an issue here?

Comment: @Wolfie As a not too big example, `A=rand(5e3, 20)`, then the computation of `B` may takes a while. In fact, this kind of computations have to be repeated in my code, so that I need this step to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over rows you can precompute indexes of rows and iterate over columns:

```
nbcols = size(A, 2);

[r, c] = find(tril(true(nbrows)));

rc = [r c];

for i = 1:nbcols
    B(:, i) = sum(reshape(A(rc, i), [], 2), 2);
end
```

Equivalent possibly less efficient solution:

```
for i = 1:nbcols
    B(:, i) = A(r, i) + A(c, i);
end
```

As `A` is very large the completely vectorized solution:

```
B = A(r,:) + A(c,:);
```

shouldn't be more efficient than the loop version.

Comment: @rahema1 Many thanks for your replies. This is really much better when using indexes. I will add an example to show my tests as follows.

Comment: Note that the result depends on the size of `A`. For a matrix of size `[5e3 x 20]` on Octave the best result can be achieved by: `B = A(r,:);B+=A(c,:);` May the MATLAB equivalent not work better than the full verctoized version: `B = A(r,:);B= B + A(c,:);`

Comment: I've tested on MATLAB, `B=A(r,:); B=B+A(c,:);`  seems as fast as `B=A(r,:)+A(c,:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the suggestion of @rahnema1 here is a test result about three possible ways. Let us generate matrix `A` as `A=rand(1e4,20);`

Method 1: using indexes and vectorization

```
tic
nbrows = size(A,1);
[r, c] = find(tril(true(nbrows)));
B = A(r,:) + A(c,:);
toc
```

Terminate in 12.8 seconds.

Method 2: using indexes and loops

```
tic
nbrows = size(A,1);
nbcols = size(A, 2);
[r, c] = find(tril(true(nbrows)));
rc = [r c];
B=zeros(nbrows*(nbrows+1)/2,size(A,2)); 
for i = 1:nbcols
    B(:, i) = sum(reshape(A(rc, i), [], 2), 2);
end
toc
```

Terminate in 34.8 seconds.

Method 3: using loops only

```
tic
idx=1;
nbrows=size(A,1);
B=zeros(nbrows*(nbrows+1)/2,size(A,2)); 
for i = 1:nbrows
  for j = i:nbrows
    B(idx,:) = A(i,:) + A(j,:);
    idx = idx + 1;
  end
end
toc
```

Terminate in 85.1 seconds.

As a conclusion, Method 1 (using indexes and vectorization) is the fastest one. Thanks again for the nice answer! If anyone finds better way than method 1, I will be very happy to see that.